# In azure B2C, is there a possibility to have an array/vector as user attribute?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are using the **user-attributes** from **azure b2c** for our web-app. Anything related to our users we save there (e.g. id, email, address,...) . Now we have a problem, that we also have one attribute, which is a vector of short strings. For example:

```
bookmarks=["abc123", "abc456", "abc789"]
```

Does azure support this, or do we have to put this attribute in our own db? Is there a best practise on where to put what?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [stringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations) e.g.

```
collection: ["someone@outlook.com", "admin@contoso.com"]
```